# AWS IoT Rule results in empty Payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

My weather-station is publishing its status via MQTT to AWS IoT.

The message is published to topic
`$aws/things/my-weather-station-001/shadow/update` and  looks like this:

```
{
 "state": {
   "reported": {
      "temperature" : 22,
      "humidity" : 70,
       ....
      "wind" : 234,
      "air" : 345
   }
 }
```

After message is received I have create a rule to store it in AWS DynamoDB the rules select statement is:

`SELECT state.reported.* FROM $aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted`

And when this works well, whilst I am sending messages containing `state.reported` field.

However sometimes to the topic `$aws/things/weather-station-0001/shadow/update` are sent "control" messages telling device to switch on an LED or some other part. These messages would be usually sent by an app or a controlling server and look like this **notice that instead of `reported` field it has`desired`**

```
{
 "state": {
   "desired": {
      "led1" : "on",
      "locked" : true
   }
 }
```

So when these messages are arriving, they ARE STILL processed by the rule and arrive to the DynamoDb table with `{}` empty payload.

Is there any way to force the Rule to ignore messages not containing `state.reported` element?

Comment: If you are trying to update the thing shadow over MQTT the topic should be `$aws/things/<thing_name>/shadow/update`

Comment: Thank you @cementblocks for your suggestion, however I believe you're incorrect in this case. In order to receive an update which is "confirmed" by AWS IoT you need to subscribe to `$aws/things/<thing_name>/shadow/update/accepted` or if you're interested in deltas to `../shadow/update/delta`.  
If you subscribe only to `..shadow/update` you are NOT really using shadows service, but simply getting back the update you sent (including when it is malformed).

You can read more on that on  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-shadow-mqtt.html#update-accepted-pub-sub-message

Comment: This line in your question `The message is published to topic $aws/things/my-weather-station-001/update and looks like this:` has the incorrect topic, you should publish to `$aws/things/my-weather-station-001/shadow/update`

Comment: @cementblocks sorry, my bad. That was just a typo in the question (will fix it). The actual code is posting as you said to `$aws/things/my-weather-station-001/shadow/update`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a where clause to your SQL statement. Try

`SELECT state.reported.* FROM $aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted WHERE state.reported <> ''`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but now I am getting empty `{}` payloads as the result of this rule execution :S

Comment: Maybe the `VALUE` operator can help? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/aws-iot-sql-syntax-expressions.html